Projective Kernel or Image of Homomorphism between Projective Modules
Note: A simple "yes" or "no" answer would be sufficient. I just need confirmation.
Let $R$ denote a Noetherian commutative ring (e.g. $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$). If $A,B$ denote projective finitely generated $R$-modules, and $f\in$ Hom$_R(A,B)$, then the kernel and image of $f$ will be projective. Is this a true statement?
For context: I am currently looking to show that the full triangulated subcategory $\mathbf{T}$ of derived category $D(\mathbf{A})$ (where $\mathbf{A}$ denotes the category of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$-modules) containing all perfect complexes will not have a t-structure denoted by $(\mathbf{T}\cap D^b(\mathbf{A})^{\leq0},\mathbf{T}\cap D^b(\mathbf{A})^{\geq0})$. I have gotten almost everything done, just one last step is that I need to show that $\ker(f:P\to Q)$ or im$(f:P\to Q)$ is not projective.
Thanks all! Appreciate any help I can get.

No, neither the image nor the kernel of a homomorphism between finitely generated projectives need be projective.

In your example $R=\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$, we have the $R$-module homomorphism $f\colon R\to R$ given by multiplication by $x$.  The kernel and image of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$ (with $x$ acting as multiplication by $0$).
It remains to show that $\mathbb{C}$ is not projective.Consider the surjective map $s\colon R\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $1\mapsto 1$.  Every surjective map to a projective module splits, so it suffices to show that $s$ does not split.
Let $t\colon \mathbb{C}\to R$ be a splitting, so $st=1_\mathbb{C}$.  Then  $t(1)=1+ax$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}$.  Then in $R$ we have:
$$x=x(1+ax)=xt(1)=t(x1)=t(0)=0,$$
gives us the desired contradiction.
